# 500 Error using PUT on Google API

Tags: google-drive-api

I can upload a XLSX file to a google drive service account. However, I can not update it anymore. It used to work until around 2 weeks, but now I am receiving a 500 Error. Any idea why? I deleted the file, created a new one, tried it again and again. But nothing works.

An error occurred:

> Error calling PUT
>   https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/XXXXX-HQGKo?newRevision=false&uploadType=media:
>   (500) Internal Error

Comment: Earlier this morning Google Drive was [experiencing an issue](http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=4&iid=1f2d8893f37e64b26c637349d78df762) that was returning 500 errors. Is this still occurring?

Comment: yes I stillt get the problem as of right now...